# How to tell Apache Camel BindyCsvDataFormat to ignore blank lines?

Tags: apache-camel, bindy

I have a CSV file that ends with a few empty lines. I would like to unmarshal each non-empty line into a Java object using BindyCsvDataFormat as follows:

```
//within my RouteBuilder class
from("{{route.from}}")
.unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(MyClass.class).)

@CsvRecord(separator = ",", skipField = true, skipFirstLine = true, generateHeaderColumns = true, allowEmptyStream = true)
@Data
public class MyClass {

    @DataField(pos = 1, required = true)
    @NotEmpty
    private String myString;
    
    @DataField(pos = 2, required = true, pattern = "M/d/yyyy")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDate myDate;

    @DataField(pos = 3, required = false, pattern = "M/d/yyyy")
    private LocalDate notRequiredDate;
}
```

When Camel attempts to unmarshal an empty line (containing only a carriage return followed by  a line feed), it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The mandatory field defined at the position 1 is empty for the line: 5
```

How do I tell Apache Camel to ignore empty lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see that this is possible with Bindy. A potential workaround would be to split the file on line endings, then conditionally unmarshal individual lines through Bindy based on whether or not the line is empty.

Answer (score 2):

A possible alternative could be to filter out empty lines **before** unmarshalling.
This can be easily done using the `filter` EIP and `simple` language:

```
from("direct:demo")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
    .streaming()
    .filter( simple("${body.length} > 0") ) 
    .unmarshal(new BindyCsvDataFormat(MyClass.class))
```

Comment: Sorry @Jeremy Ross. I saw too late your (similar) answer